# How to return error in Laravel Passport using Guzzle in json format

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

When the Password grant is successful it returns format in json but when error returns an html format Exception in Laravel 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I answered it on my own, adding config to guzzle `'http_errors' => false` returns the error to json.

```
  public function loginapi(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $password =  $request->password;
   $http = new Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://restapi.dev/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 3,
            'client_secret' => 'Lh66IODOP4pZHF676xZA8ghQiIt9OepqYHVzFEIN',
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'scope' => '',
        ],
        'http_errors' => false //add this to return errors in json
    ]);
        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
}
```